# How to export/import constructor functions?

Tags: javascript

With the following UMD export:

```
(function(factory) {

    module.exports = factory();

} (function() {


    function test() {
        this.param = 'This is a test';
    
        this.init = function() {
            console.log(this.param)
        }
    
        this.init();
    }

    return test;
    
}));
```

I tried to import the `test` function, and to initialize an instance

```
import {test} from 'path/to/test'


const myTest = new test();
```

Result:

> test is not a constructor

Comment: `test` isn't supposed to be a constructor. It was already called on line 3 in the first code block.

Comment: Well don't use UMD, use ES6 module `export` declarations?

Answer (score 0):

Either correct the import

```
import test from 'path/to/test'
```

or the export

```
return { test };
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a global browser global export; don't export it inside the function. More information: [Export module pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133852/export-module-pattern).

Try the following `.js` code:

```
module.exports = (function (factory) {
  return factory();
}(function () {
  function test() {
    this.param = 'This is a test';
    this.init = function () {
      console.log(this.param)
    }
    this.init();
  }

  return test;
}));
```